# bionic Release 404 Not Found [IP: 10.251.36.205 80]

Tags: 18.04

I installed ubuntu server 18.04.1 and when I run sudo apt update I get the following error message:

... bionic Release 404 Not Found [IP: 10.251.36.205 80]

I can't perform a apt update.  I am stuck.  Please help.

Also:

The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.Updating from such a repository can't be done securely...

Comment: A 10.x IP is private. Are you using a VPN, proxy, or university/corporate network?

Comment: education network

Comment: I can ping other websites.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I would guess you need to talk to your school's IT.